# Do I need a virtual destructor for a second interface class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I've got classes called "Base" and "Derived".

```cpp
struct Base {
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;

    virtual void DoStuff() = 0;
};
```

The "Base" class needs virtual destructor and it's understandable. Also I don't allow copying of this class

```cpp
struct Derived : Base {
    Derived() = default;
    ~Derived() override = default;

    void DoStuff() override { /*...*/ }
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> a = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    a->DoStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

Now let's introduce other classes called, I don't know, `Callable` and `DerivedCallable`

```cpp
struct Callable
{
    virtual void Call() = 0;
};
```

```cpp
struct DerivedCallable : Base, Callable
{
    DerivedCallable() = default;
    ~DerivedCallable() override = default;

    void DoStuff() override { /*...*/ }
    void Call() override { /*...*/ }
};
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> a = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    a->DoStuff();

    {
        auto callableA = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedCallable>(a);
        if(callableA) {
            callableA->Call();
        }
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Base> b = std::make_shared<DerivedCallable>();
    b->DoStuff();
    
    {
        auto callableB = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<DerivedCallable>(b);
        if(callableB) {
            callableB->Call();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`Derived` does not inherit from `Callable`, so `callableA` is nullptr, thus the if statement won't execute the `Call()` function.

`DerivedCallable` on the other hand inherits from `Callable` and the `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` will increase the ref count of the object to 2, so when the `callableB` gets out of the scope the object won't be deallocated, only the refcount will decrease to 1 and then the main function will deallocate `b`.

Does `Callable` need to have a virtual destructor?

Comment: See for yourself: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_polymorphic. Use that on your type. Good question by the way, +1

Comment: @Edziju What  are that Base& operator(const Base&) = delete; and     Derived() = default;
    Derived() override = default;?

Comment: My bad, should be `operator=` and `~Derived() override = default`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You only need a virtual destructor if you are ever going to delete a derived class object through a base class pointer.

Since you are using `std::shared_ptr`, you don't need any virtual destructors because the shared_ptr stores a correctly typed deleter (no matter how you cast it).

If you are ever going to own a `DerivedCallable` object with a `Callable` pointer (`std::unique_ptr<Callable>` or something else that calls `delete` on a `Callable*`), then it should have a virtual destructor. However, if you only ever have non-owning references with `Callable*`, then you don't strictly need the virtual destructor.

Adding a virtual destructor when the class already has other virtual members is very cheap, so it's fine to add it so that you don't have to worry about accidentally `delete`-ing it wrong.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just needed to make sure :D. Thanks

Comment: @Edziju • In this situation of having a pointer that should not be used to `delete` the object, I put in a `protected: virtual ~Foo() = default;`.  Technically, the `virtual` should not be needed, but it helps to squelch irrelevant compiler warnings.

Comment: There is an exception form shared_ptr holding proper deleter when raw pointer is converted to shared_ptr. It is better to have virtual destructor if any other member function is virtual.

Comment: @MarekR A raw pointer of a derived type converted to a shared_ptr of the base type (like `std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived)`) correctly stores the derived type's destructor. If it's cast to the base type as a raw pointer, then you have an owning pointer of the base class type and you would need a virtual destructor. I do agree that having a virtual destructor anyways is good (see the last point)

Comment: @Artyer I mean more complex example when raw pointer points to base class. In such case it will be unable to detect proper dtor. It is extreame corner case but it can happen. Also it is better to have class which properly works with `std::unique_ptr` .

Comment: hmmm are you sure about that? `Callable` got a pure virtual method

Comment: "Since you are using std::shared_ptr, you don't need any virtual destructors because the shared_ptr stores a correctly typed deleter (no matter how you cast it)." that isn't quite true (just 90% true).  It is make shared that makes this safe, and/or initial construction through a pointer to a type that can be safely deleted, not shared ptr itself.  Mentioning this would improve the answer (outside of comments)

Answer (score 7):

It depends. In theory, `Base` doesn't *need* a virtual destructor. You need a destructor to be virtual when you lug around an object which has a different dynamic type than its static type.

In your example, you have `Base` pointer that really points to a `Derivied` object. If you were not to make `~Base()` virtual, then, destroying that object would exhibit undefined behaviour -- likely by failing to destroy the `Derived` portion of the object.

So, as long as you don't plan to have an (owning!) pointer to your object through a particular base class, that base class's destructor need not be virtual.

Comment: *"fail to destroy the Derived portion of the object."*. It would be UB instead, even if, in practice, chances are that it is that behavior.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just needed to make sure :D. Thanks